# How to prevent everyone from adding local admins using GPO

Tags: group-policy

I want to prevent everyone, including local administrators, from adding users to the Administrators group.

How can I do this using GPO?

Comment: Disable anyone except a Active Domain Administrator from the [ability to add local users to the computer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730760.aspx). You do understand that a Active Domain permission trumps any local Administrator permission right?

Comment: We have a security group added as a local admin with over 100 people in it; I need to keep them as local admins but prevent them from adding any other local admins.

Comment: If you have an Active Domain they are basically normal Users but with local Administrator permissions. You can add/remove any permission you want through a active domain group policy.  The link should have provided you some knowlege to find the coresponding active domain group policy.